# How many App Services for one application?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

As an a Azure app service plan can host unlimited apps (api or web), for the same service plan, would API apps function any differently (e.g. perform worse or better) if they are deployed to multiple Web API apps or a single app?

E.g. I have 500 APIs for line of business application. From a performance and management perspective is deploying to one app better or worse than deploying to multiple apps? From a management perspective I can see it being more work having multiple apps (e.g. configuring CORS for each app separately).

Comment: It perhaps goes without saying, but keep in mind that App Services don't share memory. So if your App Services are loading and caching any shared data, they're going to require more processing time (to load these independently) as well as memory (to separately store) this duplicate data.

Comment: That said, if these are true "microservices", you might want to evaluate porting these over to Azure Functions instead of Azure App Services. Azure Functions is optimized for a large number of small, stateless APIs. The startup time for these is a lot faster and it's cheaper to scale them than an App Service Plan.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to answer this from the outside without knowing anything about your app is “it depends”. There’s no reason a decently sized modern app which leverages a modern front end framework in the browser talking to web apis can’t run on a single app service with an appropriately sized app service plan.

Start there and then measure performance and watch your system health under normal load. If the app needs it, scale up the app service plan. If you want something more robust, and your app is written to support it, scale out your app service plan.

App service is so easy to scale and measure just do the work to get it off the ground. Set up pipelines to deploy your code and azure assets. Measure, tweak, deploy.